# While installing android plugin for eclipse indigo get the following error

Tags: android, eclipse

An internal error occurred during: "Computing size".
Incompatible profile file name. Expected format is {timestamp}.profile.gz (or {timestamp}.profile) but was ._1316138460759.profile.gz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do restart of Eclipse and it will download fine

Answer (score 2):

Well, I came across this problem while installing both Maven and ADT 1.8 on my Ubuntu machine. However, restarting eclipse didn't solve the problem for me.

Further investigating this, I found that this is a Mac Profile Issue. (I have dual boot machine running Mac/Windows/Ubuntu). Following [command](http://newdailyblog.blogspot.in/2012/05/ecliplse-error-incompatible-profile.html) help me solve the issue:

```
cd /path/to/your/eclipse/folder
find . -iname '._*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```